# Upgrading from next js 9 to 12 and webpack 4 to 5 throws error while running build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

Getting this error while running npm run build. I upgraded my next js version from 9 to 12 and upgraded webpack from 4 to 5. Dev is working fine, the issue only persists when running npm build. It would be helpful if anyone can help me fix this problem, as i am facing this from a long time.

```
HookWebpackError: Cannot read property 'traceChild' of undefined
    at makeWebpackError (/Users/xyz/Desktop/cd-webapp-react/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:41630:9)
    at /Users/sagar/Desktop/cd-webapp-react/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:25321:12
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/xyz/cd-webapp-react/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:140036:10), <anonymous>:48:1)
-- inner error --
TypeError: Cannot read property 'traceChild' of undefined
    at TerserPlugin.optimize (/Users/xyz/Desktop/cd-webapp-react/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/src/index.js:72:44)
    at /Users/sagar/Desktop/cd-webapp-react/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/src/index.js:243:31
    at fn (/Users/sagar/Desktop/cd-webapp-react/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:22798:19)
    at _next3 (eval at create (/Users/sagar/Desktop/cd-webapp-react/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:140036:10), <anonymous>:40:17)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/sagar/Desktop/cd-webapp-react/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:140036:10), <anonymous>:57:1)
    at fn (/Users/sagar/Desktop/cd-webapp-react/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:22754:9)
    at _next2 (eval at create (/Users/sagar/Desktop/cd-webapp-react/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:140036:10), <anonymous>:53:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/sagar/Desktop/cd-webapp-react/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:140036:10), <anonymous>:67:1)
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/sagar/Desktop/cd-webapp-react/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:140036:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at fn (/Users/sagar/Desktop/cd-webapp-react/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:22748:45)
caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
TypeError: Cannot read property 'traceChild' of undefined
    at TerserPlugin.optimize (/Users/sagar/Desktop/cd-webapp-react/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/src/index.js:72:44)
    at /Users/sagar/Desktop/cd-webapp-react/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/src/index.js:243:31
    at fn (/Users/sagar/Desktop/cd-webapp-react/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:22798:19)
    at _next3 (eval at create (/Users/sagar/Desktop/cd-webapp-react/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:140036:10), <anonymous>:40:17)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/sagar/Desktop/cd-webapp-react/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:140036:10), <anonymous>:57:1)
    at fn (/Users/sagar/Desktop/cd-webapp-react/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:22754:9)
    at _next2 (eval at create (/Users/sagar/Desktop/cd-webapp-react/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:140036:10), <anonymous>:53:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/sagar/Desktop/cd-webapp-react/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:140036:10), <anonymous>:67:1)
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/sagar/Desktop/cd-webapp-react/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:140036:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at fn (/Users/sagar/Desktop/cd-webapp-react/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:22748:45)
```

below is my next.config.js

```
const hash = require('string-hash');
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const path = require('path');
const dotenv = require('dotenv-flow');
const withBundleAnalyzer = require('@next/bundle-analyzer')({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true',
});
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const pkg = require('./package.json');

// This plugin is used for measuring build time
const SpeedMeasurePlugin = require('speed-measure-webpack-plugin');

const smp = new SpeedMeasurePlugin();
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

dotenv.config({ silent: true });

const { S3_PUBLIC_URL, S3_BUCKET_DIR } = process.env;
// remove trailing slashes '/'
const IMAGE_HOST = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_IMAGE_HOST.replace(/\/$/, '');

module.exports = withPlugins([[withBundleAnalyzer]], {
  distDir: '_next',
  assetPrefix:
    isProd && S3_PUBLIC_URL
      ? `${S3_PUBLIC_URL}/${S3_BUCKET_DIR}/${pkg.version}`
      : '',
  eslint: {
    // Warning: This allows production builds to successfully complete even if
    // your project has ESLint errors.
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
  swcMinify: false,
  future: { webpack5: true },

  webpack: (config, { isServer, defaultLoaders }) => {
    config.resolve.extensions = ['.js', '.jsx'];
    config.resolve.alias.public = path.join(__dirname, 'public');
    config.resolve.alias['~'] = path.resolve(__dirname);
    config.resolve.alias['lodash-es'] = 'lodash';
    config.externals.push('moment');

    if (!isServer) {
      // config.plugins.push(new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/\*.{spec,test}.js/));
      config.module.rules.push({
        exclude: [/\*.{spec,test,data}.js/],
      });

      // console.log(config.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups);

      // config.optimization = {
      //   ...config.optimization,
      //   minimize: true,
      //   minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()],
      // };

      // config.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups.shared = {
      //   ...config.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups.shared,
      //   minChunks: 3,
      // };
    }

    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: [
          defaultLoaders.babel,
          {
            loader: require('styled-jsx/webpack').loader,
            options: {
              type: (_fileName, options) => options.query.type || 'scoped',
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              additionalData: `$IMAGE_HOST: "${IMAGE_HOST}";`,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      // {
      //   test: /\.svg$/,
      //   issuer: /\.(js|ts)x?$/,
      //   use: ({ resource }) => [
      //     {
      //       loader: '@svgr/webpack',
      //       options: {
      //         svgoConfig: {
      //           plugins: [
      // {
      //   cleanupIDs: {
      //     prefix: `svg${hash(path.relative(__dirname, resource))}`,
      //   },
      // },
      //             { removeViewBox: false },
      //           ],
      //         },
      //       },
      //     },
      //   ],
      // }
      {
        test: /\.svg?$/,
        oneOf: [
          {
            use: [
              {
                loader: '@svgr/webpack',
                options: {
                  prettier: false,
                  svgo: true,
                  // svgoConfig: {
                  //   plugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }],
                  // },
                  titleProp: true,
                },
              },
            ],
            issuer: {
              and: [/\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx|md|mdx)$/],
            },
          },
        ],
      }
    );

    return isProd ? smp.wrap(config) : config;
  },
  experimental: {
    amp: {
      skipValidation: true,
    },
  },
});
```

Can anyone please help in resolving i have tried fixing this but no results. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).